# How to get a Confluence page through REST in UTF-8 in Java?

Tags: java, http, java-8, utf-8, confluence

I'm trying to get a Confluence page through their API REST. I need that page has the UTF-8 enconde, because I'm using special characters on my pages.

I'm using this call now:

```
URL url = new URL(https_url);

InetSocketAddress inet = new InetSocketAddress(proxy, port);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, inet);

HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", auth);

// JSON
StringBuilder finalJson = new StringBuilder();
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
BufferedReader buffered = new BufferedReader(input );

String json;
while ((json = buffered .readLine()) != null) {
    finalJson.append(json);
}
```

But with this, my json is written in ASCII.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is this Cloud or Server?

Comment: It's cloud, my friend.

Comment: One thing to fix: make sure your `InputStreamReader` parses the data as UTF-8 by specifying the character encoding: `InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` otherwise it will use the default encoding of your system, which may or may not be UTF-8.

Comment: Thak you so much! This input configuration solves my problem! ♥

Comment: Just requesting UTF-8 doesn't guarantee the response is really in UTF-8.

Comment: Try adding `conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");` You may or may not have to change `conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");` to `conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");` Since the official [`application/json` registration](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259) doesn't define a `charset` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

InputStreamReader has another constructor, it takes two params, the first one is InputStream, the second one is charset name,maybe you can have a try.

`InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf8");`

Comment: As has said @Jesper a little higher first, that is the solution. Thank you!